# SVG icons with Tailwind seem to scale based on content of sibling element

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm displaying a list of items, each in a row with `space-between`, but the SVG icon seems to scale its size depending on the length/size of the sibling element.

Here's a screenshot of what is happening:

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <svg class="h-6 w-6 mr-5 fill-current text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title>Link</title>
      <path d="M 5 3 C 3.9069372 3 3 3.9069372 3 5 L 3 19 C 3 20.093063 3.9069372 21 5 21 L 19 21 C 20.093063 21 21 20.093063 21 19 L 21 12 L 19 12 L 19 19 L 5 19 L 5 5 L 12 5 L 12 3 L 5 3 z M 14 3 L 14 5 L 17.585938 5 L 8.2929688 14.292969 L 9.7070312 15.707031 L 19 6.4140625 L 19 10 L 21 10 L 21 3 L 14 3 z"></path>
    </svg>
    <div>
      <a href="https://google.com/">This is a short link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="flex items-center">
    <span class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap">
      <span class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap"> 19 Sep, 2023 </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <svg class="h-6 w-6 mr-5 fill-current text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title>Link</title>
      <path d="M 5 3 C 3.9069372 3 3 3.9069372 3 5 L 3 19 C 3 20.093063 3.9069372 21 5 21 L 19 21 C 20.093063 21 21 20.093063 21 19 L 21 12 L 19 12 L 19 19 L 5 19 L 5 5 L 12 5 L 12 3 L 5 3 z M 14 3 L 14 5 L 17.585938 5 L 8.2929688 14.292969 L 9.7070312 15.707031 L 19 6.4140625 L 19 10 L 21 10 L 21 3 L 14 3 z"></path>
    </svg>
    <div>
      <a href="https://google.com/">This is a very long link that has a lot of text that will wrap to the next line and maybe even another line where is will cause the svg icon to shrink which is not what I want at all.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="flex items-center">
    <span class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap">
      <span class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap"> 19 Sep, 2023 </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the same code on Tailwind Play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/1S2SZuytDZ

I've tried a few variations of styles on the SVG element and other elements, but I can't seem to keep the SVG icons a constant size. I would like the icon on the left to stay the same size, no matter the length of the content in its sibling element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used shrink-0 to prevent the SVG icon container from shrinking. This ensures that the icon maintains a consistent size even when the link text is long and wraps to the next line.

here is the code after change in tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/YZjnGlHEiJ